# In App billing Android: Item unavailable , The item that you requested is not available for purchase

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am experiencing problem with the in app billing for android.

- The developers email and the test account email is not the same
- my product item is set to publish
- I have the product id set to "inappbillingtest" and my call in the code set to BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "inappbillingtest");
- and I also have double checked the public key is correct

Does anyone have any other ideas as to why my in app billing is not working?

I am able to get the android.test.purchased to work without any issues.

Anyone’s help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you uploaded the correctly-signed APK to the market? This might happen a few times, and should be ok if you try after some time if everything else is fine :)

Comment: I have uploaded the signed APK to the market and i have installed the same apk to my phone. I have set the apk to activated in the market admin as well. I have tried both activated and deactivated.     Within the code do I have the productid correct?  I know android has predefined id android.test.purchased  I have set the product item id to inappbillingtest  so i make the call to inappbillingtest, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this should work. Can you post your logs and the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem yestoday. I recently write code in lua, I just do three steps. First, change my build.setting by http://blog.anscamobile.com/2012/03/getting-started-with-android-in-app-billing/. Second, change my Manifest.xml by http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html
   When you change the product id's state, it will work after a few hours,maybe three hours.
I could not remember exactly.
   So, third, be patience, wait a few hours.